# Passing a Custom mask to the LSTM data for training and validation

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I have an LSTM architecture ready:

```
input1 = Input(shape=(1500, 3))
lstm = LSTM(units=100, return_sequences=False, activation='relu')(input1)
outputs = Dense(150, activation="sigmoid")(lstm)
model = Model(inputs=input1, outputs=outputs)
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer="adam",
                  metrics=["accuracy"])
```

The `LSTM` layer supports a calling argument called `mask`.

The way I'm reading the data is by using **two generators, one iterates through training files and the other through the validation files** (so on the `.fit` method I pass the training and validation generators).

```
model.fit(
        x=training_generator,
        epochs=10,
        steps_per_epoch=5, # there are 5 files
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        validation_steps=5, # there are 5 files
        verbose=1
    )
```

Therefore each file will have a given mask (one for the training file, another for the validation file). Therefore my question is, how can I specify which mask to use?

Comment: So then each input pattern has (1500,3) features and (1500,3) mask then? Is it a boolean mask? How are the masks stored compared to the features (first all features, then all masks or corresponding mask right after the features)?

Comment: Also, it seems the generator is generating all the content from one file as one batch, correct? If so, I don't think you have to specify `steps_per_epoch` and `validation_steps`; the generators will generate all the training / validation data in 5 steps anyway and then stop. How many samples are in each file / batch?

Comment: Yes the shapes you mentioned are correct. It is indeed a boolean mask, and they are store as numpy arrays. So you have .npy files for features and files for the masks. The generator is iterating through a list that contains the numpy arrays of the features. One file is one batch yes, if I don't specify the steps_per_epoch it will keep calling the generator until the input is exhausted. The number of samples varies per file/batch, some can have around 5k samples, ohters 12k.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I found to work was to transform the data during the preprocessing stage. If you replace the values in your data, according to the mask, with an number you know is not in your data, for instance 0 or -999, you can then add another layer to the architecture called `Masking`. This layer has a parameter called `mask_value` which will be the same number you used to transform your data:

```
input1 = Input(shape=(n_timesteps, n_channels))
masking = Masking(mask_value=-999)(input1)
lstm1 = LSTM(units=100, return_sequences=False,
             activation="tanh")(masking)
outputs = Dense(n_timesteps, activation="sigmoid")(lstm1)
model = Model(inputs=input1, outputs=outputs)
model.compile(loss=keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
              optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01))
```

This  way you can then pass this as the input to the LSTM (since LSTMs allow this, some other types of layers do not).